# How to keep last items in view when adding them to listview?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, scrollview

I have a ListView where I dynamically add ListElements. The ListView has a maximum of 10 items that can be in view, so I also have a ScrollBar. When I add the 11th+ item, I always want it to scroll into view.

```
ListView {
    id: logListView
    delegate: logListViewDelegate
    model: logListModel

    anchors.fill: parent

    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
}

ListModel {
    id: logListModel
}

Component {
    id: logListViewDelegate
    Item {
        height: 44
        width: logListView.width

        Text {
            id: countText
            width: 18
            font {
                pixelSize: 16
                family: variables.globalFont
            }
            color: colors.foregroundColor3
            text: index+1

            anchors {
                left: parent.left
                leftMargin: 7
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
        }
        Text {
            id: timeText
            width: 96
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
            font {
                pixelSize: 24
                family: variables.globalFont
            }
            color: colors.foregroundColor1
            text: time

            anchors {
                left: countText.right
                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
        }

        Text {
            id: unitText
            width: 18
            font {
                pixelSize: 16
                family: variables.globalFont
            }
            color: colors.foregroundColor3
            text: unit

            anchors {
                left: timeText.right
                leftMargin: 6
                bottom: timeText.bottom
                bottomMargin: 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a button outside of the listview that when clicked just does:

```
logListModel.append({
 time: myTime, unit: myUnit
})
```

The new item just gets added to the bottom of the list and is hidden when there are more than 10. When adding an item , I would like the list to automatically scroll to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ListView`, scroll to the bottom by changing the currentIndex when `onCountChanged` is called (when your model has changed):

```
ListView {
  id: logListView
  delegate: logListViewDelegate
  model: logListModel

  anchors.fill: parent

  ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}

  onCountChanged: {
    var newIndex = count - 1 // last index
    positionViewAtEnd()
    currentIndex = newIndex
  }
}
```